# Accessing data from blogger api

Tags: html, google-blogger-api

I am trying to develop an Android app with Angular 2 using Blogger API.

How can I display html codes saved in JavaScript variable on a webpage. The APO data from blogger is as html codes.

Answer (score 0):

This document explains [how to get started using the Blogger API](https://developers.google.com/blogger/docs/3.0/getting_started).